# C++ fstream is only saving the first character of a string

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, fstream

As the title says I've a problem with fstream. I've made a singleton logging class which uses fstream to save the logging messages in a file.

I use the IDE XCode. In Visual Studio 2013 the code works fine.

Header file:

```
#ifndef Logger_hpp
#define Logger_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Logger
{
private:
    static Logger* loggerPtr;
    std::fstream fs;

    //To ensure no one else can instantiate Logger.
    Logger();

public:
    enum MessageType
    {
        ERROR,
        WARNING,
        INFO
    };

    static Logger* Instance();
    void LogFunc(std::string msg, MessageType type);

};

#endif /* Logger_hpp */
```

CPP file:

```
#include "Logger.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Logger* Logger::loggerPtr = NULL;

Logger* Logger::Instance()
{
    if (!loggerPtr)
    {
        loggerPtr = new Logger;
    }

    return loggerPtr;
}

Logger::Logger()
{
    fs.open("docker.log", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
}

void Logger::LogFunc(std::string msg, MessageType type)
{
    std::cout << msg;

    switch (type)
    {
        case ERROR:
            fs << msg;
            break;
        case WARNING:
            fs << msg;
            break;
        case INFO:
            fs << msg;
            break;
    }
}
```

Main file:

```
int main() {

    Logger::Instance()->LogFunc("Hello.", Logger::INFO);

    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open("docker_test.log", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
    fs << "Why does this work?!";

    system("pwd");

    return 0;
}
```

Log outputs:

```
cat docker.log -> outputs H
cat docker_test.log -> outputs Why does this work?!
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Text output must end with a newline. Insert `'\n'` at the end of each insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be related to the fact that you don't [flush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/) your `fstream`.  As it is buffered, the buffer is then not written to the file. As at the end of your code, the `Logger` is not destroyed (inconvenience of using a raw pointer), the buffer is not flushed either.

It works for the stream you have opened in `main()`, because the local stream is automaticallt destroyed (and closed) when leaving the function.

Suggestion:

```
fs << msg;   // for every logging output in syour switch 
fs.flush();  // add a flush
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for the added information Christophe.

Comment: You're welcome.  Another possibility would have been change slightly the code to use a [`unique_ptr<Logger>`](http://ideone.com/okrKuA) instead of a raw pointer to be sure it's closed at the end.  On the other side, the flush has the advantage of writing to the file even if your app crashes in the middle of its operations.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you never `delete` your *singleton* so the `std::fstream` never gets flushed.

I would do your *singleton* a little differently. Instead of using a *pointer* I would use a static instance local to the `instance()` function like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Logger
{
private:
    std::fstream fs;

    //To ensure no one else can instantiate Logger.
    Logger();

public:
    enum MessageType
    {
        ERROR,
        WARNING,
        INFO
    };

    static Logger& Instance(); // return reference
    void LogFunc(std::string msg, MessageType type);

};

Logger& Logger::Instance()
{
    // put the static in the function to ensure creation time
    static Logger logger; // use a static instance, not pointer
    return logger;
}

Logger::Logger()
{
    fs.open("docker.log", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
}

void Logger::LogFunc(std::string msg, MessageType type)
{
    std::cout << msg;

    switch (type)
    {
        case ERROR:
            fs << msg;
            break;
        case WARNING:
            fs << msg;
            break;
        case INFO:
            fs << msg;
            break;
    }
}

int main() {

    Logger::Instance().LogFunc("Hello.", Logger::INFO);

    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open("docker_test.log", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
    fs << "Why does this work?!";

    system("pwd");

    return 0;
}
```